Antlr4: why is my grammar not matching indent
I have a grammar with
bullet:indent star  string date? tag? EOL; 
where
SPACES:[ \t]+;
indent:SPACES?;

When I run this grammar on the following line
    * [X]  Monitoring and analyzing signals and waveforms (2024-02-22)  #21ebdd44

I get
extraneous input '    ' expecting {<EOF>, '# ', SPACES, STAR}
Why is it not matching the input to SPACES which it is expecting? What is wrong with my grammar defination?
Edit1:

The complete grammar is at https://github.com/dyumnin/task2report/blob/main/grammar/task2report.g4
Sample input file is at https://github.com/dyumnin/task2report/blob/main/tests/test.md
You can reproduce the error by running

antlr4-parse grammar/task2report.g4 top  tests/test.md                                                                                                           
line 2:0 extraneous input '    ' expecting {<EOF>, '# ', SPACES, STAR}

antlr4-parse is available at https://github.com/antlr/antlr4-tools/

Always write a driver program that prints out all the tokens for the input string. Verify the tokens are exactly what you expect. Also, for the error, print out the line and column for the location of the error. Verify that it is where you think it is.

And always include an MCVE when asking a question on a public forum. See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

@kaby76 I am not sure what 'driver program' means here, can you please point me to an example.

@BartKiers, I have updated the question with an MEW

You already have a "driver" https://github.com/dyumnin/task2report/blob/42b08f1dfa6e8c46a6ae700a990aeb1448369a42/src/task2report/task2report.py#L23-L29 . Just add code to print out the tokens.

From Google: "What is a driver program in software development?" ---> "A driver program in software development can refer to a few different things, including .... a program used for testing code."

@kaby76 Thanks, I managed to printout the tokens and figure out and fix the issue, '    ' was being interpreted as WORDS
